# Disabling Automatic Latex Plugin (ATP) mappings

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-tex, abbreviations, plugin-atp

I’m trying to use the [Automatic LATEX Plugin for Vim (ATP)](http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/), and found it has quite neat features. However, I do not like input abbreviations, so I tried to disable them using

```
let g:atp_no_env_maps=1
let g:atp_imap_define_greek_letters = 0
let g:atp_imap_define_math = 0
let g:atp_imap_define_math_misc = 0
let g:atp_imap_define_diacritics = 0
let g:atp_imap_define_fonts = 0
let g:atp_tab_map = 1
```

in my `.vimrc`. But that did not cut it, it seems. In particular, when I
enter `'` or `` ` `` or `\s` or `\c`, the cursor does not advance until I press the
next key.

What is the recommended way to disable these imaps, but still have the
`<TAB>` imap?

Comment: Very related: [How can I prevent plugins from overwriting my key mappings?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3710/51).

Answer (score 2):

If nothing helps, you can always explicitly `:unmap`/`:unabbreviate` the keys in a filetype event autocommand or using the ftplugin/tex.vim file. That should make it work. Don't forget, that you probably need the `<buffer>` modifier for those commands.

But perhaps, you want to ask the author of that plugin directly. It seems, he will be better suited to answer this question.

Looking at the help, it seems `:ToggleIMaps` should at least partially get rid of the <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd> mappings.